# Access textbox value from ashx page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages, ihttphandler

This is my Form Tag from The Master Page:

`<form id="form1" runat="server" action="Handler.ashx" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

I have a `TextBox` in my Content Page:

`<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>`

I want to access the `TextBox` value in the `Handler.ashx` page Or Send the `TextBox` value as a query string in the `action` attribute like this `<form id="form1" runat="server" action="Handler.ashx?textBoxVal=SOMETHING" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Is this possible?

Comment: I think we can check this in Request.Params[""]

Comment: @Murali  I tried it but no luck .

Comment: I think the problem is getting the client id or unique id i guess

Comment: This is what i am doing `context.Request.Params("TextBox1")` , i am calling it from code behind, so how do i get the unique id or the client id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive the problem would be accessing the ID (ClientID or UniqueID ) of your Text box in GenericHttpHandler.

But it could be possible if you set the **ClientIDMode="Static"** as a TextBox Property, if you use ***ASP.Net 4*** and try below code

```
 context.Request.Params("TextBox1")
```

Comment: Already tried..no luck...just in case this helps my page does not post back..can this be the reason?